# Gradle testScoverage failing with NoClassDefFoundError for a project utilizing MINA SSHD

Tags: gradle

I have a set of classes that use MINA SSHD (org.apache.sshd). These classes have tests that have worked with version 1.7.0 of MINA. I'm now moving to 2.8.0, and have re-run the tests. I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for two specific classes from MINA:

```
22:40:46.606 [sshd-SshServer[55f94b13](port=8022)-nio2-thread-2] DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSessionImpl - readIdentification(ServerSessionImpl[null@/127.0.0.1:56869]) client version string: SSH-2.0-APACHE-SSHD-2.8.0
Exception in thread "sshd-SshClient[ef9d35b]-nio2-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.sshd.common.util.logging.LoggingUtils
    at org.apache.sshd.common.util.logging.AbstractLoggingBean.debug(AbstractLoggingBean.java:82)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector.access$200(Nio2Connector.java:42)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector$ConnectionCompletionHandler.onCompleted(Nio2Connector.java:180)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector$ConnectionCompletionHandler.onCompleted(Nio2Connector.java:116)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.lambda$completed$0(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:38)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:37)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

and

```
22:59:22.798 [sshd-SshServer[55f94b13](port=8022)-nio2-thread-2] DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.session.SessionFactory - messageReceived(Nio2Session[local=/127.0.0.1:8022, remote=/127.0.0.1:57245]) failed NoClassDefFoundError to handle message: Could not initialize class org.apache.sshd.common.SshConstants$LazyMessagesMapHolder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.sshd.common.SshConstants$LazyMessagesMapHolder
    at org.apache.sshd.common.SshConstants.getCommandMessageName(SshConstants.java:200)
```

It's odd that it says it can't find a class that is part of the sshd-common artifact, where other classes are found without issue.

In my main dependencies, I'm using 2.8.0:

```
        dependency group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-common', version: '2.8.0'
        dependency group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-core', version: '2.8.0'
        dependency group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-scp', version: '2.8.0'
        dependency group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-sftp', version: '2.8.0'
```

In the specific project where the code and tests are written, I pull in the specific versions too:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-common', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-core', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-scp', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-sftp', version: '2.8.0'

  compile project(':commands:expect4j')
  compile project(':common:utils')
    compile group: 'net.jcazevedo', name: 'moultingyaml_2.12'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-reflect', version: scalaVersion
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.scala-logging', name: 'scala-logging_2.12'
}

apply from: new File(rootProject.projectDir, 'gradle/scala.gradle')
```

No other references to `org.apache.sshd`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

[Mina 2.8.0](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/sshd-2.8.0/pom.xml) uses slf4j version 1.7.32.

Try to add this dependecy version.

```
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.32'
```